# Help with accessing module variable inside Python function?

Tags: python, variables, module, global-variables, local-variables

I have the following function in a Python module called dictbuilder.py:

```
def my_dictbuilder(reader_o, writer):
    fieldnames = ('name', 'number')
    reader = csv.DictReader(reader_o, fieldnames = fieldnames, delimiter="\t")
    my_dict = {}
    id = 0
    for row in reader:
       id += 1
       my_dict[id] = row['name'], row['number']
       id += 1
    return(my_dict)
```

I have imported and called this function from a module called main.py. I would like to also use the `my_dict` variable from the dictbuilder.py module I have imported into main.py. When I try to print`my_dictbuilder.mydict` I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'my_dict'`

Can anyone help me figure out how to access the my_dict variable from my main.py file? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where does the fimo_dict come from?

Comment: You need to post a working (or nonworking) example of what failed.

Comment: @GabrielRoss Sorry, I made a typo. It should read my_dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're returning `my_dict`, so just store the return value in your main module when you call it.

```
my_dict = dictbuilder.my_dictbuilder(reader_o, writer)
```

Comment: Weird, I tried this before asking the question and it didn't work. I tried it again and it worked this time. Many thanks!